# Not displaying quantity of object in my product cart on UI

Tags: react-redux

I am using API of a fake store, so when I add a product to my cart I need to update the quantity of this product in the cart and update the quantity on UI. The problem is that product quantity is updating in global state, but not updating on UI. Could you please give any advice on that? Thank you in advance !

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TO_CART":
      const newItem = action.payload;
      const exist = state.products.find((item) => item.id === newItem.id);
      if (exist) {
        exist.qty += 1;
        return {
          ...state,
          quantity: state.quantity + 1,
        };
      } else {
        newItem.qty = 1;
        return {
          ...state,
          products: state.products.concat(newItem),
        };
      }
  }
};
```

Comment: Please share the value of `initialState`

Comment: const initialState ={
    products: [],
    
    
}

Answer (score 0):

A reducer function should always return the new state, not mutate the existing one. When you do `exist.qty += 1`, you are mutating the state. Also, in the if block, you are adding a new property in your state when you do `quantity: state.quantity + 1,`.

Assuming each product at least has these properties: `id` and `quantity`, this should work:

```js
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TO_CART":
      const newItem = action.payload;

      // Clone existing products array
      let updatedProducts = [...state.products];

      // Find the index of the product you want to add
      const existingIndex = updatedProducts.find((item) => item.id === newItem.id);

      // If the product exists (it will have an index of > -1)
      if (existingIndex > -1) {
        // Increase its quantity
        const updatedProduct = { ...updatedProducts[index], quantity: ++updatedProducts[index].quantity };

        // Update the item in the array
        updatedProducts.splice(existingIndex, 1, updatedProduct);
      } else {
        // Product was not found in products - so add it at the end, with quantity set to 1
        updatedProducts = [...updatedProducts, { ...action.payload, quantity: 1 }];
      }

      // Return the state
      return { products: updatedProducts };
  }
};
```